# apply multiple conditional filters on a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I'm a new flutter developer and would like to use multiple filters on my List.
I'm using a ListView :

```
ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
MealCard(_customList[index]),
itemCount: _customList.length,
                          ),
```

and my Meal class have the following properties:

```
 Meal {
final String id,
final String title, 
final String imgUrl, 
final bool isLowCalorie,
final bool isVegan,
final bool isBreakfat, 
final bool isDinner,
final bool isLunch}
```

I'd like to apply different filters based on the booleans included within my class; I have some methods that look something like this:

```
 List<Meal> get breakfastFilter {
    return _meals.where((element) => element.isBreakfast).toList();
  }

  List<Meal> get lunchFilter {
    return _meals.where((element) => element.isLunch).toList();
  }

  List<Meal> get dinnerFilter {
    return _meals.where((element) => element.isDinner).toList();
```

However these methods allow me to create a single list, what if I wish to add additional filters together and create a combination of two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late to the game, so let me throw my name in the hat. I'd refactor it a bit so as to support more than one filter, otherwise you won't know upfront how many filters will be applied.

I'd create an enum called **MealType**:

```dart
enum MealType {
  none,
  isLowCalorie,
  isVegan,
  isBreakfast,
  isDinner,
  isLunch
}
```

Refactor the class to take a list of **MealType** values:

```dart
class Meal {
  final String? id;
  final String? title;
  final String? imgUrl;
  final List<MealType>? mealTypeFilter;
  
  Meal({ this.id, this.title, this.imgUrl, this.mealTypeFilter });  
}
```

The data would look like this:

```dart
List<Meal> meals = [
    Meal(
      id: '1001',
      title: 'Pancakes',
      imgUrl: '',
      mealTypeFilter: [
        MealType.isBreakfast
      ]
    ),
    Meal(
      id: '1002',
      title: 'Chicken Wings',
      imgUrl: '',
      mealTypeFilter: [
        MealType.isLunch
      ]
    ),
    Meal(
      id: '1003',
      title: 'Yogurt',
      imgUrl: '',
      mealTypeFilter: [
        MealType.isLowCalorie,
        MealType.isBreakfast,
        MealType.isVegan
      ]
    )
  ];
```

I'd collect the applied filters in a **Set** to avoid duplicates, and filter the meals whether the **mealTypeFilter** collection contains any of the applied filters:

```dart
Set<MealType> appliedFilters = {};
  List<Meal> filteredList = [];
  
  List<Meal> getFilteredList() {
    if (appliedFilters.isEmpty) {
      return meals;
    }
    
    return meals.where((m) => m.mealTypeFilter!.any((f) => appliedFilters.contains(f))).toList();
  }
```

I'd call the **getFilteredList()** method every time in the build method when I trigger a button that contains the filter to be applied and populate the **filteredList** with which I render a **ListView** with the results:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    filteredList = getFilteredList();
    
    // rest of the code here
}
```

See [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/c69b56b4137f212554ffa6e5e575ede0) for the full code, and run it through DartPad so you can see it in action, like this:

[image]

Hope this works.

Comment: thanks man it works fine you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something  like this:

```
 bool filterItem(element){
    return element.isVegan&&element.isBreakfat;
  }
    
  _meals.where((element) => filterItem(element)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do it but you can try to use boooleans combined with optional parameters like this:

```
getMealFilter(_meals,
    {bool lookForBreakfast = false,
    bool lookForVegan = false,
    bool lookForLunch = false}) {
  return _meals
      .where((element) =>
          (lookForBreakfast && element.isBreakfast) ||
          (lookForVegan && element.isBreakfast) ||
          (lookForLunch && element.isLunch))
      .toList();
}
```

I just put 3 filters, but you can easily add the rest. How this works is that if, for example, `lookForBreakfast` is false, `element.isBreakfast` is ignored. (false and something is always false), and so on for the others parameters.

Comment: It works, however it seems to be a lengthy condition. If I have a large number of booleans